# Create a spark dataset that has additional option fields using an existing dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, option-type, apache-spark-dataset

I have a case class as follows:

```
case class student_address(studentId:String, address:String)
```

The values from a csv are read into the dataset - studentAddressDS, which is mapped to the above case class

There is a second case class as below:

```
case class refined_address(studentId:String, address:String, number:Option[Int], road:Option[String], city:Option[String])
```

I need to create another dataset - refinedAddressDS which is mapped to the refined_address case class. This dataset should have values from the first one for the fields studentId and address. The 3 Option fields should be null/empty. No default values though.

I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
val refinedAddressDS[refined_address] = studentAddressDS.map(x=>{
    (x.studentId, x.address, None, None, None)
  }).as[refined_address]
```

Gives: MatchError - None.type

I tried replacing None with null and that too gave MatchError.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm fairly new to spark and scala.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```scala
case class RefinedAddress(studentId:String, address:String, number:Option[Int], road:Option[String], city:Option[String])


val refinedAddressDS: Dataset[RefinedAddress] = studentAddressDS.map(sa => RefinedAddress(sa.studentId, sa.address, None, None, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional fields to existing DataFrame like below.

```
scala> // Option 1 : Pass default values in case classes so that you don't have to pass None explicitly.

scala> case class student_address(studentId:String, address:String)
defined class student_address

scala> case class refined_address(studentId:String, address:String, number:Option[Int] = None, road:Option[String] = None, city:Option[String] = None)
defined class refined_address

scala> spark.emptyDataset[student_address].map(row => refined_address(row.studentId, row.address))
res9: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[refined_address] = [studentId: string, address: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> // Option 2 : You can get schema from new case class & apply to existing DataFrame by adding null as a default values for missing columns, like below. This is useful when you have more fields/columns.

scala> val newColumns = spark.emptyDataset[refined_address].schema.map{ s => if(studentAddressDS.columns.contains(s.name)) col(s.name) else lit(null).cast(s.dataType).as(s.name)}
newColumns: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(studentId, address, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS number, CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS road, CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS city)

scala> studentAddressDS.select(newColumns:_*).as[refined_address]
res10: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[refined_address] = [studentId: string, address: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> studentAddressDS.select(newColumns:_*).as[refined_address].printSchema
root
 |-- studentId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- number: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- road: string (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
```